# Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Tags: c#

This program is guessing a number from a dice (1,6) User vs Enemy Computer. So my problem is if the User guess and Computer guess are correct. But i'm stuck at the Operator && cannot be applied to operands.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isCorrectGuess = false;
        Random random = new Random();

        int enemyRandomNum;

        int randomNum = random.Next(1, 6);

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the dice number guessing game!");
        Console.WriteLine("A number between 1 and 6 will be generated.");
        Console.WriteLine("Who guess the correct number will have + 1 point.");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");

        while(!isCorrectGuess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your guess.");
            int playerGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("Enemy AI will now have a guess. ");

            Console.WriteLine("...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            enemyRandomNum = random.Next(1,6);
            Console.WriteLine("Enemy AI rolled " + enemyRandomNum);

            // here is the error

            if (playerGuess && enemyRandomNum > randomNum)
            {

            }


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `playerGuess` is of type `int`. You can't use that directly in a conditional statement. Use `playerGuess > 0` or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
if (playerGuess && enemyRandomNum > randomNum)
```

Semantically means:

> If `playerGuess` is true
> and
> `enemyRandomNum` is greater than `randomNum`

But `playerGuess` *can't* be `true` because it's not a boolean, it's an integer.  If you want to test is *both* of these values are greater than `randomNum` then you need to specify that:

```
if (playerGuess > randomNum && enemyRandomNum > randomNum)
```

Comment: Joel I will edit the code. Please bear with me. I need to show who's got the correct guess, and will have a 5 match and who will reach the 5 points will won the game.

Comment: please see the updated code.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn please see the updated code.

Comment: @McDz: If you have a new question to ask, that's best done by posting an entirely new question.  Modifying the code in this question so that it no longer contains the problem you were asking about makes the question confusing and unhelpful to future readers.

Comment: okay sorry my bad. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

`playerGuess` is an integer but you treat it as a bool.  Try something like

```cs
(playerGuess > 0) && (enemyRandomNum > randomNum)
```

Another solution is that you can convert `playerGuess` to a bool.  Try

```cs
bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(playerGuess);
```

or

```cs
bool b = playerGuess != 0;
```